# Python dictionary code

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

So I need to write a python code for getting all the keys in a dictionary with unique values. For example

```
my_dict = {4:3, 5:3, 6:4, 9:8}
```

the program should print

```
[6, 9]
```

Because the 3 is repeated in the values. I do not know how to see if the values are different and then how to remove them as there is no ".remove()" for dictionaries. I have tried making a list of keys and values, then trying to mutate them in some way, but I have had no luck. Thanks

Comment: You don't have a dict , you have a set .

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Fixed

Comment: PS -- thers is no `.remove()` method for dicts because you are supposed to use `del` as indicated in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count the values with a [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) dict then only keep keys from you dict with a value that is equal to 1 in the Counter dict.

```
my_dict = {"4":"3", "5":"3", "6":"4", "9":"8"}


from collections import Counter

cn = Counter(my_dict.itervalues())
print([k for k,v in my_dict.iteritems() if cn[v] == 1])
['6', '9']
```

Comment: @JMacr, no worries, it takes a bit more memory to store the Counter dict but the solution is `O(n)